# How to hide a property just in post request description of swagger using swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am new to ASP.NET Core and this question looks simple but I couldn't find a proper solution online. So here's the problem.
This is the structure of the class that I am using.

```
public class Alert
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string AlertId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

This is the description for the Post request API in swagger.

```
{
  "alertId": "string",
  "type": "string"
}
```

Since I am using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation `alertId` in the post request is optional. 
My aim is to hide `alertId` from the post request description only.
I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1, EF Core(3.1.1) and Swashbuckle.AspDotNetCore(5.1.0).
Please Help.
Thank you.

Comment: It is better not to return your 'Alert' object to the client.
You can create a separate model (for example 'AlertDto') which would contain only the properties you want to return in a response.

Comment: As Ivan has said, create a class that models the data you need from the user. After getting the data, you can map it to to the `Alert` entity.

Comment: As Ivan has said, create a class that models the data you need from the user. After getting the data, you can map it to to the `Alert` entity.

Comment: I have been trying to do this for a while now. I wanted to hide/exclude the ID property from HttpPost using a custom HttpPostIgnore-attribute. But when I think about it, it would be confusing if I have a Schema (model) in Swagger act different across methods from how it is documented in the Schema section. I dont want my API to be too out of standard, so I am discontinuing my attempt, and create separate DTOs for different methods instead. Just wanted to put my perspective out there :)

Comment: hi @mathkid91 , is my answer what you want?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` package, it allows you to mark that some properties are only displayed in the input parameters, and some are only displayed in the output.

In your case, you want to hide the `AlertId` in the input parameter of the post, you just need to do this by the `[SwaggerSchema]`:

```cs
public class Alert
{
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public string AlertId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

See more about it in the [Documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

In the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`, enable annotations within in the Swagger config block:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tag! It sounds like what I want, but its not working as expected in any of my projects - at least not by just installing the NuGet and adding the tag. I will try follow the documentation step by step and check it out again, in case I have done something funny in my code, or have missed some SwaggerSchema initialization.

Comment: @mathkid91 yes, initialization with `c.EnableAnnotations()`

Comment: Thank you! Everyone suggests using JsonIgnore, but that prevents serialization, so even your GET requests hide the field. Glad to see there was an actual solution out there, and a totally straight-forward one at that.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. I was trying to use JsonIgnore but it did'nt work at all. Now using Annotations from SwaggerSchema, everything is working. Thanks!

Comment: [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)] dos not work for me. Parameter is still shown in OpenApi.json (as read only thow)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the AlertId field to ensure that the post request will not get the content of the AlertId.

```
  public class Alert
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string AlertId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

    }
```

Here it the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle then simply changing the Setter to internal will prevent it from showing in the Post request schema:

```
public class Alert
{
    public string AlertId { get; internal set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```